# Problem with textbox on change in my gridview

Tags: c#

Please help me I get a strange error in my gridview when I try to call an event with OnTextboxChange, the gridview add a line.

I have no data :
https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/13/m9xm.png

When I put a number on the textbox txtEvoN, txtN1 changed but I have a new line in my grid :( :( :(

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/13/swbt.png

Please help i am confused :(

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView runat="server"  ID="maGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
        OnRowEditing="maGrid_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="maGrid_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="maGrid_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="maGrid_RowDeleting"
        DataKeyNames="ProduitId" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Produit" ItemStyle-Width="19%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >  
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Produitlibv") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>     
              </ItemTemplate>   
              <EditItemTemplate>    
                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbProduitlibv" Text='<%# Eval("Produitlibv") %>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"/>     
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <FooterStyle Width="19%" /> 
              <FooterTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduitlibv" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"/>                                                       
              </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="N" ItemStyle-Width="15%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("N") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbN" Text='<%# Eval("N") %>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"/>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <FooterStyle Width="15%" /> 
              <FooterTemplate>                                                
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtN" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"/>


              </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="% évolution" ItemStyle-Width="5%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("EvoN") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbEvoN" Text='<%# Eval("EvoN") %>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"/>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <FooterStyle Width="5%" /> 
              <FooterTemplate>                                              
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtEvoN" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnTextChanged="txtEvoN_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Insert"/>
              </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="N+1" ItemStyle-Width="10%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("N1") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbN1" Text='<%# Eval("N1") %>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"/>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <FooterStyle Width="15%" /> 
              <FooterTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtN1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Insert3"/>

             </FooterTemplate>

          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
              <ItemTemplate>                                             
                  <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../images/edit2.png"  alt="edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Modifier une vente" Width="15px" Height="15px" />
              </ItemTemplate>

              <FooterStyle Width="10%" /> 
              <FooterTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../images/plus2.png" alt="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Add" ToolTip="Ajouter une vente" Width="15px" Height="15px" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>                                               
              </FooterTemplate>

          </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#9e408b" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="White" Height="30px"></HeaderStyle>
      <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#9e408b" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9e408b" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" />
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Label id="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" />
    <asp:Label id="lblMessage2" runat="server" Text="" />

</form>
```

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
             DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
             using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con2.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select ProduitId, Produitlibv,N, EvoN, N1  from[dbo].[ProduitsVentes] where IdUser='" + "ccd6941a-a028-4600-bfa5-ef07c0b6dd82" + "'", con2);
                sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            }
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                maGrid.DataSource = dtbl;
                maGrid.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
                maGrid.DataSource = dtbl;
                maGrid.DataBind();
                maGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                maGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                maGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dtbl.Columns.Count;
                maGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data";
                maGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#ventes';", true);
            }

            }


        }
protected void txtEvoN_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtN1, txtN, txtEvoN;
            txtN1 = (TextBox)maGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtN1");
            txtEvoN = (TextBox)maGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEvoN");
            txtN = (TextBox)maGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtN");

            if (txtN1.Text == "") txtN1.Text = "0";
            if (txtEvoN.Text == "") txtEvoN.Text = "0";
            if (txtN.Text == "") txtN.Text = "0";

            txtN1.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(txtN.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtEvoN.Text)) / 100);                     
        }
```

Comment: The source code you've provided is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. Please post the full page code. Where and how do you Bind the data source?

Comment: In the pageload, I updated the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I hope my solution will help. This is an almost obsolete technology now. Wouldn't you consider switching to MVC? To React or whatever is trending right now? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
```

This is the statement that causes all your troubles.

You are naively trying to display an empty row to make your footer visible. But this grid view row, when the grid view is posted back, does not bring with it the manual operations you carried out on it. It assumes that there is a row at position zero and that's why the `Edit` action button is also displayed.

Here is a fix.

First of all, to prevent code duplication, we move the "No Data" row creation into a method with an overload to handle both PostBack and !PostBack cases:

```
private void InsertNoDataRow()
{
    InsertNoDataRow(null);
}

private void InsertNoDataRow(DataTable dtbl)
{
    if (dtbl != null)
    {
        dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
        maGrid.DataSource = dtbl;
        maGrid.DataBind();
    }
    maGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
    maGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    maGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = maGrid.Columns.Count;
    maGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data";
    maGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#ventes';", true);
}
```

Then in Page_Load event handler; we call them accordingly. Please note that we are also calling this method when this is a PostBack:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        . . .
        . . .
        if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            maGrid.DataSource = dtbl;
            maGrid.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            InsertNoDataRow(dtbl);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (maGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text == "No Data")
        {
            InsertNoDataRow();
        }
    }
}
```

And there is only one thing left, which you probably are already handling. When a record is added (The Add action is invoked), we need to re-bind the data table to get rid of the dummy "No Data" row. Because you haven't posted the code for this method, I can only provide the required steps as comments:

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Insert into DB.

    // Now we need to remove row 0 if it is still the dummy row showing "No Data".

    // Reselect the data table and bind again.
    // This time we expect at least one row to exist.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have just an error on maGrid.DataBind(); in InsertNoDataRow(DataTable dtbl).
```'System.Data.DataRowView' ne comporte pas de propriété appelée 'ProduitId'.'```

Can you help me please for the code in  ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)